# RHEL Equivalent of AIX's chuser login=false rlogin=false

Tags: redhat, sudo, su

On AIX, I can disable login/remote login by setting the attributes listed to false, but I will still be able to su from other users, and sudo as the user.

Is there an equivilant in RHEL to the above?  I tried locking the password (usermod -L), and I can still sudo, but not su.